# [8.0]Why does the PURCHASE ANALYSIS in REPORTING show incorrect price amounts.?

Tags: odoo, reporting, price

ODOO ver8.0

[image]

[image]

Purchase analysis is showing incorrect values, as well as other reporting like sales.etc the price doesnt display correctly.

Comment: What is the problem here? 100,03 / 2 = 50,025 which rounded to 2 digits is 50,03

Comment: oh i see. is the purchase order in company currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION

For all those having same problems, you need to go to currencies under ACCOUNTING -> MISC
-- and then add 1.000 to the rate above the existing rate. Somehow reporting starts to show the correct currency. Thanks guys

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Because in purchase order report price will be converted to company
>   currency first by applying currency rate of the purchase order date.

If you want to check the query for purchase order report, you can refer this view **view purchase_report** or you can see the code for that in 
**purchase => report => purchase_report.py** file.

Comment: But this is also the case for the sales analysis, price is showing incorrectly

Comment: In any report all prices and amount must in common currency this is why it's converted to company currency.

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/d464212e49.png
Price of product is 50 moroccan dirhams without tax

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/d464212e49.png
Price of product is 50 moroccan dirhams without tax